# iPython crashing %reset

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda

I'm trying to learn my way around the iPython shell and I absolutely love it so far.  I keep running into a bit of a snag though, anytime I try to reset all of my variables via the %reset magic command, iPython decides to crash on me, regardless of my input (y/n).
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling my Anaconda distro, as well as uninstalling all previous versions of python that I'd installed on my computer, but for some reason I can't seem to fix it.    I'm using Anaconda 4.3.1 with Python 3.6.

Comment: You must post more details such as O.S. and version, the error output...

Comment: What do you mean by crash?  Why are you doing `reset`?  I never do.

Comment: OS Windows 10.0.14393.  I'm running IPython from cmd.  Whenever I try to run %reset I get a pop-up that says 

"""Python has stopped working

A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.  WIndows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."""

And then it asks me if I would like to debug or just close the program.  When I go to debug it, Visual Studio freezes up and I have to ctr + alt + del to end the task.  If I just close the program then I get booted back into batch in the cmd shell.  Working out of Wes McKinney's book.  This is only day 2 in IPython.

Comment: Can the downvoter of this post explain themselves? I don't think this should have been downvoted (I upvoted). It's a very legitimate question.

Comment: It's all good, it's like Reddit... some people will downvote anything just because they can.  Thanks for the help everyone, though!  I'll look into Pycharm and try to see if there's a way to contact the IPython dev team about this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've found a legitimate bug! It crashed for me too, in both powershell and plain old cmd:

[image: Crash in Powershell]

However, you can get around it on Windows 10 by installing and using Pycharm:

[image]

I would highly recommend using Pycharm on Windows anyway. It's a great IDE that can give you things the windows shells can't. For example, autocomplete, refactoring tools, custom key bindings, and (apparently) a safe environment to run ipython in.